# Let's not waste time trying to close old unanswered zero-score questions

Tags: discussion, review

If a question is

- a month or more old
- has the score of 0
- has no answer

there is no need to close it. If you find it's unclear or otherwise unsuitable for the site, just downvote it. With the score of -1, it will be automatically deleted by a script that runs weekly.

There are few people who review closevotes regularly on the site. I used to do it more often, and am trying to get back to doing it now, but I'd rather not face a stream of mind-numbingly boring, long-forgotten posts unless it's **necessary**.

Comment: Not one per week; there were 6 in the queue this morning, most of which fit the above description.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with downvoting questions that one finds unclear or otherwise unsuitable for the site. Downvoting, in addition to being not so friendly, doesn't educate the OP, unlike closing, which gives a reason to the OP.

Comment: Then it makes sense that you will not downvote those questions, while I will.

Comment: @CrazyIvan Actually, you gave a good example: one could otherwise downvote and leave a comment :-)

Comment: The guidance for the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You, of course, can vote how you like, but downvoting is _specifically for_ questions that are unclear or otherwise unsuitable for the site. And, really, it's not a signal to the author so much as a signal to future readers.

Comment: @ale unsuitable is very broad. Eg if is unsuitable because it's off topic even though it was a well researched question,  then imho it's best to close as off topic.