# How to treat questions that are non-relevant anymore?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, obsolete-questions

I was looking at old questions, to find some questions without answers that it's worth answering, and I came across this question: [YouTube videos embedded in Facebook are not playing when in HTTPS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26296/177684).

The thing is that this question is no longer relevant as it is, since [Facebook doesn't embed videos in posts anymore, they're just links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116557/177684).

So, should I answer that it's not relevant anymore? Do something else about it?

I'm asking in general, not specific on that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a custom close reason under "Off-topic" for web applications that are no longer available; it also applies to the *features* that are no longer available.

> Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Additionally, an old unanswered question gets automatically deleted after a while, so it would be enough to downvote that question since it's no longer useful. (Arguably it was not useful to begin with, as nobody could reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Related: [Let's not waste time trying to close old unanswered zero-score questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/88163)

Comment: That question already vanished, but it may have some historical value.