# Please remind people that questions and answers must contain the data

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

Questions *and* answers often contain links to Google sheets but miss the data *in the question*. Perfect example for both Q and A<sup>*</sup>:

[Splitting the contents of a comma separated cell into new rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132407/splitting-the-contents-of-a-comma-separated-cell-into-new-rows)

1. Can we please emphasize (in comments) that sample data (numbers or formulas; actual vs. expected results; input vs. output) should be in the question (layout as code, most times), and that a link to a live sheet is welcome but not enough.
   Many of those links will die because the OP deletes the sheet after (s)he got an answer.
2. What would be a good text to remind them to do so?
   Something like?:

> Please add sample data to your question (actual vs. expected or input vs. output). A link to a Google sheet is welcome too, but not enough.

<sup>* Changed in the meantime; See edit history</sup>

Comment: Have you considered to add this question to [2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4656/88163)?

Answer (score 2):

For those posts that include a link to Google Sheets, or any other external content, what about this thinking on something that could apply to posts of any site from Stack Exchange Network ?

<sup>Adapted from the [wiki of link-only-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) tag form Meta SE</sup>

> ## Provide context for links
>
> A link to *external content* is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

*external content* could be replaced to something more specific like Google Sheets, an discussion forum, blog, Stack Overflow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For questions that doesn't include a link to external content but doesn't include enough details, I usually add something like

> Please add a brief description of you search, research and attempts efforts as is suggested on [ask]

If the poster is a new contributor I include `Welcome`

If the question have one day but less than one month Also I vote to close as `too broad` or `unclear what you are asking` but if the question was posted some time ago I down-vote it.

Related

- [Let's not waste time trying to close old unanswered zero-score questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/88163)